# Space complexity when converting HashSet to ArrayList

Tags: java

Recently, I have been solving problems in Leetcode. In general, there are many problems where we are supposed to return an ArrayList, array, etc.

For example, in this question https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-duplicates-in-an-array/description/ we are supposed to return an ArrayList. The space complexity for this question is strictly O(1). That is, ignoring the size of the returned ArrayList, we should only use only constant space.

I find that there are many questions that are solvable using HashSet, but I can't return the HashSet (like in the case of the question I mentioned) because the return type is ArrayList/List.

Using the java ArrayList constructor, we can convert the HashSet to ArrayList directly. I can write a program like below to return the List.

```
return new ArrayList<>(hashset);
```

When I try to convert HashSet to ArrayList, will copies of n elements present in the hashSet be made separately inside the memory or will an ArrayList created in this way essentially "wrap" the underlying array of the HashSet and does not copy the elements or allocate additional memory for them?

Comment: The source code of both `ArrayList` and `HashSet` is included with Java. You can inspect this and see they have separate copies of the references.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(hashset)` copies references to objects only.  That constructor has no idea how to make copies of objects.  (It would pretty hard to implement that.  Would it try to clone them?  Serialize them?  Look for a copy constructor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert a HashSet to an ArrayList in Java using the ArrayList constructor, it will create a new ArrayList with separate memory allocation. The constructor called is:

> public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection,
> in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

The elements of the HashSet are copied into this new ArrayList. Therefore, it does not "wrap" the underlying array of the HashSet, but rather allocates additional memory for the new ArrayList. This operation does not maintain the constant space complexity O(1), as it requires O(n) space where n is the number of elements in the HashSet.

This leetcode problem, expects you to make use of detail given in the task which allows you to solve it in expected time and space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is `n` elements, then your HashSet contains `n` elements, and so does the ArrayList. It's a complete copy, so the memory requirement of both the arraylist and the hashset existing side by side (which they will, here) grows linearly to the input size. But it is about twice as large as what it would have been, had there only been an arraylist and no other data structures that grow relative to input size.

**However**,

More generally, 'the exercise is supposed to be `O(1)` except for the arraylist' **does not make any sense**. O() notation is a relative concept: It says **nothing** about the space or time usage at any given point, it **only** says something about how the memory load grows relative to input. This shouldn't be the problem unless a human is looking at this code.

Given that the exercise 'prices in' the space cost of the output arraylist, it can't then state that the *runtime behaviour* behaves differently. It grows linear to input size, it already does that due to the output array list, it is not feasible to try to disregard just the array list to witness the 'total memory usage of the method'.

The only real way to do that is to use code analysis. Leetcode does not have humans that look at your code to rate it, and as far as I know, they do not run tools that check *the source*.

Hence, whatever the problem is, I doubt its the hashset.